# Recommendation for a jquery plugin for dirty forms - Notify user that changes will be lost when exiting page

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm looking for a way to notify our users not to leave a page if the form-data was changed without saving. A warning message should appear (with the option to leave anyways or stay at the page). We're using jquery and jquery-ui, so I'd like to use a jquery plugin (optionally with a jquery-ui dialog).

Saw several options ( https://github.com/acvwilson/dirty_form, https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms), but since http://plugins.jquery.com is down now, I am wondering if I missing anything else?

Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

Try this quick plugin I made that checks for changes:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.checkChanges = function(message) {

        var _self = this;

        $(_self).bind('keyup change keydown', function(e) {
            $(this).addClass('changedInput');
        });

        $(window).bind('beforeunload ', function() {
            if ($('.changedInput').length) {
                return message;
            }
        });

    };
})(jQuery);

$('input').checkChanges('You sure about that?');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/e2EqZ/
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/e2EqZ/show/ (try refreshing the page after a change)

Answer (score 2):

Idea stolen from [Neal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505820/1250044), however I made it a bit more dynamically.

So you can apply it now on `form`-elements as well as on `input`-fields. And it uses now `$.fn.serialize` (for form-elements) and `$.fn.val` (for input-fields) instead of the `changedInput` class.

Note, it will also detect if a field was changed back to its original-state.

```
$.fn.watch = function (message) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var original = $this.serialize() || this.value;
        var changed;

        $this.on('keydown keyup change submit', function (e) {
            changed = original !== ($this.serialize() || this.value);
            if (e.type === 'submit') changed = false;
        });

        $(window).on('beforeunload ', function () {
            if (changed) return message;
        });
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y3g8c/

**Edit**

Thanks to [JonH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505764/recommendation-for-a-jquery-plugin-for-dirty-forms-notify-user-that-changes-wi/15321588#comment35614457_15321588) for his comment.

Now we get notified only if the form was **not submitted**.

Comment: How do you avoid this message on a button click?  For instance, a server side button labeled "Save" is going to do just that, save, so you don't want this message to show up when you click that button...

Comment: @JonH Thanks, I've not thought about that before. But the updated *version* should fix this issue (http://jsfiddle.net/y3g8c/). Thanks again :-*